# Полнотекстовый поиск с возможными ошибками в запросе

Tags: php, sql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Здравствуйте, стоит задача реализовать полнотекстовый поиск по сайту.
К примеру в базе данных имеется таблица `products`, в ней  поля `title`, `description`, `image`. Как реализовать поиск, чтобы он искал по ключевым словам, например "Визитки" "Везитки" "Визиктки", т.е. если пользователь ввел запрос с ошибкой, ему все равно выдало нужный результат.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: по-моему полнотекстовый поиск, и поиск с возможными ошибками в запросе это разные вещи.

Comment: рецепт прост берёте sphinx ставите на сервере, берёте apiPHP и пилите поиск.

Comment: Полнотекстовый поиск значительно отличается от точного поиска, предоставляемого базами данных, и для этого существуют принципиально отличные сервисы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен фонетический поиск. [Вот реализация на php](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?17l7lez4w7ma) и [статья о нем на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/28752/)

Там есть функция, преобразующая слова в фонетический код:

```
dmstring('Арнольд Шварцнеггер') //== 096830 479465
dmstring('Орнольд Шворцнегир') //== 096830 479465
```

Получаете код и заносите его в БД в отдельное поле.

Затем при поиске кодируйте поисковый запрос с помощью этой-же функции и ищите по полю с фонетическими кодами.